# Which apache2/php5 config should I change if I don't want the session to die?

Tags: php, session

I'm logging my admin like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin'] = TRUE;
```

When I login and stay inactive for like 10 minutes, then refresh, the session is dead and the admin is logged out.

What do I need to set either in `htaccess` or in the `php file` itself so that the session stays alive for at least 8 hours?

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with PHP sessions, other than being the intermediary between PHP and the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file and put `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in it and check the output.

The value you want to look at is [session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) and [session.gc_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).

gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

In your script that is responsible for starting the sessions, you can put
`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600); // set session data life to 1 hour`
or any other time that is suitable for your application.

Comment: I already did that, check out: http://komponenty.bellady.sk/phpinfo.php look for ``gc_maxlifetime``, it's set to a huge number already and the session still dies...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't want to want the session don't die.

It's against session nature. A session is something what ends by definition.
Lasting admin session for the 8 hours makes no sense.

If you want to auto-renew it - use a cookie. But don't touch session mechanism itself.

Comment: Your answer sounds wise. Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Sorry, I have no good example at hand at the moment but if you google for "php remember me feature" you'd get some I believe